# why answer post get minus in off-topic question

Tags: discussion, reputation, off-topic

I have posted answer of off-topic question through i got minus reputation. why? i caught this. Is this any thing happened i did wrong.

[image]

Comment: Why do you both close and answer the question? You know that closing means that the question should't be answered, right?

Comment: Some people downvote answers to very offtopic questions, ultimately people can vote as the wish

Comment: thanks i searched the question. but i didn't get. thats way i posted @ShadowWizard

Comment: For a closed post to get auto deleted, it must not have up voted answers.
For a closed post to get auto deleted, it must not have up voted answers. Therefore if I think a post should be closed and deleted, logic dictates that I should votes to close, and then down vote the questions and all answers.

Comment: but i seen  upvoted answer in some of off-topic. thats why. @IanRingrose

Comment: I didn't downvote it (or see it), but it reads like an advertisement, and I probably would have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to what MeNoTalk mentioned, your post appeared to be poorly formatted and no information as to how to use the SDK for the questioner's purpose.

It could almost be construed as spam (though that may not have been your intention), as it appears to recommend a particular service for no reason and links to various external sites.

If you are going to recommend a tool and the question doesn't specifically ask for recommendations (recommendation questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow), only do so as part of a larger answer and just to provide an example of how to do something.

Comment: it not possible to accept both answer. but your information is very helpful me. +1 for you. thanks you support

Answer (score 12):

Answering an off-topic question simply means encouraging people to ask more off-topic questions, hence the downvotes. In my opinion, whoever downvoted your answer did the right thing.

Bottom line, answering off-topic questions is the same *sin* as asking them.

Comment: other some of off-topic answers get positive reputation why

Comment: @iDev Because not everyone votes the same way.

Comment: @iDev: that's possibly because some users aren't aware of what's on-topic and think that it answers the question correctly, even if the _question_ is off-topic. For example, if there was a question asking about "what's the best C# IDE?" and someone preferred an IDE recommended, a user might upvote that answer. Users are free to downvote or upvote questions as they please, except if they are using votes to game the system (e.g. sockpuppetry).

Comment: @iDev Tends to depend on if the questions are somewhat off topic, or very very off topic. Additionally by voting to close you admit that you knew it was off topic which may have swung some people

Comment: @iDev Some questions are disputed, some think it is on-topic while some think it is not, plus the answer provided is good and adds value to the site. In your case, the question was clearly off-topic and the answer was of low quality...

Comment: Also there are many posts closed for the same reason this one that was closed used to be on-topic but aren't any longer.  So it was ok to answer at the time, but a similar question asked today would not be permissible.